# Static library include error in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, static-libraries

I have build static library with two files: blink.h and blink.c, where functions are declared in the blink.c.

Now I have created an another C project with program: controller.c, in which I have included the file blink.h by specifying #include "blink.h". I have included previous the static library in this project. When I build this project, I get the following error:

```
"blink.h no file or directory"
```

I expected that blink.h will be referred through that static lib and this error wont occur, but it is.

Comment: Might be a problem with *#include "blink.h"*. Try *#include <blink.h>*. And here is a related discussion: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

Comment: @KBart, The problem was, I compiled library as C++ and included in the C project. Thanks!